# How to display all the posts referenced to logged in user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to understand Mongoose's populate function and am so far stumped by available resources and the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Essentially I have a schema arrangement as below, and I am trying to display all the posts referenced to a user on one page rendered with ejs.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    posts: [
        {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
        }
    ]
});


var PostSchema = new Schema ({
Title: String, 
Content: String, 
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',

}
});
```

I have got passport/sessions setup, so I am able to get the id of the active user. Using this id I would like to display all of the user's posts. I have been stuck on this for hours and tried following various tutorials and different approaches, please someone put me out of my misery! How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the users first with the `ids` list (activeUserIds) then populate the `posts` and `author` fields in fetched records.

```
await User.find({'_id': {$in: [activeUserIds]}})
  .populate({
    path: 'posts',
    model: 'Post',
    populate: ({
      path: 'author',
      model: 'User'
    })
  });
```